# How to filter specific records from the below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table (*Mytable*) with values like below;

```
CustNo Audit   History   Inputter Authoriser

 1     CHANGE  CURRENT    XYZ      XYZ
 2     CHANGE  BEFORE     XYZ      XYZ
 2     CHANGE  CURRENT    TOM      TOM
 3     ADD     NEW        TOM      TOM
```

I need to filter out only the records if Inputter and Authoriser have values 'XYZ' with  having Audit = 'CHANGE' and History = 'CURRENT', BUT it can have Audit and history as CHANGE and BEFORE respectively for Inputter and Authoriser have values 'XYZ' and other records

My expected output is as below:

```
CustNo Audit   History   Inputter Authoriser

 2     CHANGE  BEFORE     XYZ      XYZ
 2     CHANGE  CURRENT    TOM      TOM
 3     ADD     NEW        TOM      TOM
```

I used the below but I didn't get what I excepted;

```
select * from Mytable
where  (Inputter != 'XYZ' and Authoriser != 'XYZ' and Audit != 'CHANGE' and History != 'CURRENT' )
```

Can some one please correct me, how to achieve my expected output. Thanks in advance.

**Excuse me to edit my requirement,below is the new exceptation; **

now there is an another scenario needs to be added in my existing requirement,
below is the table records;

```
CustNo Audit   History   Inputter Authoriser

 1     ADD     NEW        Sasha    Sasha      
 1     CHANGE  BEOFRE     MAX      MAX
 1     CHANGE  CURRENT    XYZ      XYZ
 2     CHANGE  BEFORE     XYZ      XYZ
 2     CHANGE  CURRENT    TOM      TOM
 3     ADD     NEW        TOM      TOM
 3     CHANGE  CURRENT    MAX      MAX
```

If any Inputter & Authoriser have `'XYZ'` with Audit & history has `'CHANGE'` & `'CURRENT'` then that record should be removed (this is the existing working) along with the any occurrence of same`custNo` in table.

For example, here `custNo = 1` have `'XYZ'` with `'CHANGE'` & `'CURRENT'`,
 so this should be removed along with;

`custNo = 1` with `'CHANGE'` & `'BEOFRE'` for `'MAX'`and
`custNo = 1` with `'ADD'` & `'NEW'` for `'Sasha'`

To put in other words - remove any occurrence of the same CustNo *(who has `'XYZ'` in both Inputter & Authoriser field with `'CHANGE'` & `'CURRENT'` in Audit & History fields respectively)* irrespective of any Audit & history and even if that cust doesn't have `'XYZ'` in Inputter & Authoriser field.

new expected output :

```
CustNo Audit   History   Inputter Authoriser

 2     CHANGE  BEFORE     XYZ      XYZ
 2     CHANGE  CURRENT    TOM      TOM
 3     ADD     NEW        TOM      TOM
 3     CHANGE  CURRENT    MAX      MAX
```

Comment: Why there is  `CustNo = 3`  instead of `CustNo = 1` in your xpected output ?

Comment: thats what I need to filter it i.e. `CustNo =1` because `CustNo =1` have audit & history as CHANGE & CURRENT respectively. In other words any custNo with audit & history as CHANGE & CURRENT with XYZ for both Inputter and Authoriser should not be reported, rest of any scenarios should be reported.

Comment: Your logic is unclear to me, and you need to do a better job of posting clear questions on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is use `not`:

```
SELECT CustNo, Audit, History, Inputter, Authoriser
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT (
    Inputter = 'XYZ' 
    AND Authoriser = 'XYZ' 
    AND Audit = 'CHANGE' 
    AND History = 'CURRENT'
)
```

**update:** As for the new requirement, it's easy to do with not exists:

```
SELECT CustNo, Audit, History, Inputter, Authoriser
FROM MyTable t0
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable t1
    WHERE t1.CustNo = t0.CustNo
    AND Inputter = 'XYZ' 
    AND Authoriser = 'XYZ' 
    AND Audit = 'CHANGE' 
    AND History = 'CURRENT'
)
```

Comment: thanks @Zohar, my requirement is slightly changed please look in to it.

Comment: Many thanks @Zohar. your solution satisfies my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Istead of `AND` use `OR` in condition

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38a82efefcb32edeb39906fb54ed133a)

```
select * from Mytable
where  (Inputter != 'XYZ' or Authoriser != 'XYZ' or Audit != 'CHANGE' or History != 'CURRENT' )
```

OUTPUT:

```
Audit   History  Inputter   Authoriser
Change  before   xyz          xyz
Change  CURRENT  TOM          TOM
ADD       NEW    TOM          TOM
```

Comment: thanks @fa06,my requirement is slightly changed please look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to do as follows. Use a CASE statment to filter out the records for xyz matching specific condition

```
select * 
  from Mytable a
 where  CASE WHEN a.Inputter=a.Authoriser AND a.Inputter='XYZ' AND a.Audit='CHANGE' AND a.History ='CURRENT'THEN
                  NULL
             ELSE a.History
         END = a.History
```

Comment: If `History` is a nullable column, any records where it's null will not be returned by this statement.

Comment: thanks @George, my requirement is slightly changed please look in to it.

Comment: @Mar1009, do you happen to have an audit_id to decide all records which are "before"

Comment: @ZoharPeled. You are correct there. I just assumed the field is NOT NULL

Comment: No @GeorgeJoseph there is no audit_id to decide all records which are `before`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minus` set operator :

```
with t( CustNo, Audit, History, Inputter, Authoriser ) as
(
 select 1,'CHANGE','CURRENT','XYZ','XYZ'  union all
 select 2,'CHANGE','BEFORE','XYZ','XYZ'  union all
 select 2,'CHANGE','CURRENT','TOM','TOM'  union all
 select 3,'ADD','NEW','TOM','TOM' 
)
select * from t
minus
select *
  from t
 where Audit = 'CHANGE'
   and History = 'CURRENT'
   and Authoriser = 'XYZ';

CustNo  Audit   History   Inputter  Authoriser
------- ------  --------  --------  ----------
  2     CHANGE  BEFORE     XYZ      XYZ
  2     CHANGE  CURRENT    TOM      TOM
  3     ADD     NEW        TOM      TOM
```

or alternatively `not in` could be used :

```
select * 
  from t
where ( Audit, History, Authoriser ) not in 
      (
        select Audit, History, Authoriser
          from t
         where Audit = 'CHANGE'
           and History = 'CURRENT'
           and Authoriser = 'XYZ' );
```

Comment: thanks @Barbaros, my requirement is slightly changed please look in to it.